# Watching for Cordova to finish loading a page

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to get Cordova to alert me when the page finishes loading so I can bootstrap the application. However, I don't seem to be able to find any info on how to do that since Cordova's documents are sub-par.

The closest thing I've seen people do is setting the `appView.setWebViewClient()` but that appears to have been deprecated. I don't see any such method.

The last think I've seen is to create a new `SystemWebViewClient` but you need to have access to the current `SystemWebViewEngine` which I can't figure out how to get.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The [deviceready](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) event does not fit your needs?

Comment: I don't have control over the HTML/JS. So it has to happen in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://davehiren.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-cordova-402-webview-intercept.html

Long story short:

```
myWebView = (WebView) this.appView.getView();

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new SystemWebViewClient((SystemWebViewEngine) this.appView.getEngine()){
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
               super.onPageFinished(view, url);
      }
});
```

```